# Import Product - Image not working

Tags: import, product-images, avs-fastsimpleimport

Im want to import my products from a .txt file.
So far no problem. The only issue i have is that i cant link my product with an image ( i have already imported in media/import )

```
        $data = array(
        array(
            'sku' => $artikel_nr,
            '_product_websites' => array('web1','web2'),
            '_attribute_set' => convertCategorie($category)[2], // siehe auch in Kategorie tabelle
            '_type' => 'simple',
            'ean' =>  $ean_nr,
            'price' => $preis,
            'name' => $prodkttitel." ".$farbe,
            'description' => 'default',
            'short_description' => $prodkttitel,
            'long_description' => $short_description,
            ...
            '_media_image' => $artikel_nr.".jpg",
            '_media_is_disabled' => 1,
            'image' => $artikel_nr.".jpg",
            '_media_lable' => $artikel_nr.' image',
            '_media_position' => 1,
            '_media_attribute_id' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getAttributeId(),
            'small_image' => $artikel_nr.".jpg",
            'thumbnail' => $artikel_nr.".jpg",


        )

    );
```

my images are named after the sku and i already have them in the media/import.
the import is not throwing any exceptions but i cant see any pictures loaded into the produkt.

```
    $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
try {

    $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
    $import
    ->setUseNestedArrays(true)
    ->processProductImport($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($import->getErrorMessages());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Resolved by setting 777 permission to /media/import directory (and all the files into).
After the import set 777 to all /catalog/product/images then reindex and flush cache.

Comment: I can't see an issue with the poster's code, so it's my assumption too that the images cannot be read.